# How to remove a number from an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input with some values:

**HTML**

```
<input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value="29644,29650,63186,99616,101647">
```

On a click, I check if the clicked button `data attribute` has a `number` which is in that `input` `.val()` and if so, remove it:

**JS**

```
$(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
  var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId"); 
  $("#input_post_id").val($("#input_post_id").val().replace(removeThisId,''));
});
```

But the above `js` isn't remove the number. `Button` is:

```
<button data-thispostid="101647" type="button" class="removeJiku">Remove</button>
```

**Note:**

I'll need to remove the `number` and its `comma` too

Comment: You're getting the `data-thispostid` of the wrong element. `$(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId"); ` is not your button. Perhaps you want `$(this).attr("data-thisPostId"); `?

Comment: @TylerRoper that's true, however i only have one button with that class. I'll try

Comment: @TylerRoper ok yes works. Can we remove the comma too? See last comma `29644,29650,63186,99616,`

Comment: Edit your question to use the fixed code and instead ask about removing the comma. You'll have better luck that way instead of trying to chain questions together.

Comment: @TylerRoper well not going to create a question asking to remove a comma as i know I could do `.replace(",",''));` but the comma in this case is part of what I am removing. I edit it adding this bit

Comment: @rob.m  use `value.split(",").join(",")` to remove comma

Comment: @dhaker tried `.val().replace(removeThisId,'').split(",").join(",")); ` but the comma is there

Comment: @rob.m you are using wrong class to pick button element , removeId is not there on button

Comment: @dhaker I know, it's fine, others have pointed that out. I am only talking about the comma as you suggested

Comment: @rob.m   add  `removeId` class to button

Comment: @dhaker as I said,  the `this` issue is resolved but this isn't working as you suggested `$("#input_post_id").val($("#input_post_id").val().replace(removeThisId,''));.split(",").join(",")); `

Comment: @rob.m this will work for you `value.split(",").slice(0,-1).join(",")`

Comment: @rob.m Have added working and proof readed solution here, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the selector for your button is wrong, therefore you're not grabbing the attribute. You can just use `$(this)` instead.

For removing the comma, you can turn your comma-separated values into an array using `.split(",")`, remove the the ID from the array using `.filter()`, and then join the array back together with `.join(",")`.

```js
$(".removeJiku").on("click", function() {
  var removeThisId = $(this).attr("data-thisPostId");
  var $input = $("#input_post_id");

  console.log("BEFORE:", $input.val()); //For demo purposes

  var vals = $input.val().split(",").filter(item => item !== removeThisId).join(",");
  $input.val(vals);

  console.log("AFTER:", vals); //For demo purposes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value="29644,29650,63186,99616,101647">
<button data-thispostid="101647" type="button" class="removeJiku">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Well eventually you're the king :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @rob.m Thanks. To explain something as well regarding why I changed your input to be a variable: When you use a selector like `$("#my_element_id")`, jQuery scans the entire page for an element with that ID. This takes time! As you can imagine, doing that multiple times for the same element can add up - why re-search if you already found it! You can search for it once, store it in a variable, and save code repeated trips to keep looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

`$(".removeId")` is not your button. Instead you should write `$(this)` as shown in below working code.

Also the way you have replaced value will leave one `,` there, instead have done it in other way. Have splitted the values by `,` and then removed it if exists and again joined them by `,`.

```js
$(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
  var removeThisId = $(this).attr("data-thisPostId");
  var postIds = $("#input_post_id").val();
  if(removeThisId && postIds){
    postIds = postIds.split(",");
  
    if(postIds.indexOf(removeThisId) > -1){
      postIds.splice(postIds.indexOf(removeThisId), 1);
    }
     $("#input_post_id").val(postIds.join(","));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value="29644,29650,63186,99616,101647"/>
<button data-thispostid="101647" type="button" class="removeJiku">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is working but it is changing quite a bit of the original code. Works tho

Answer (score 1):

`replace()` will replace occurrence of an substring in a string, only the first instance of the value will be replaced.

`filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

`split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

`join()` method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string and returns this string.

```js
   

 $(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
      var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId"); 
      var inputVal = $("#input_post_id").val();
    
    inputVal = inputVal.replace(removeThisId,"");

    inputVal = inputVal.split(",").filter(Number).join(",");

      $("#input_post_id").val(inputVal);
      console.log($("#input_post_id").val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-thispostid="101647" type="button" class="removeJiku removeId">Remove</button>

<input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value="29644,29650,101647,63186,99616">
```

Comment: Perfects, works. Would you be able to elaborate it a bit more with an explanation for future users too? Thanks

Comment: @TylerRoper the reason because I am accepting this is because it's not changing my whole code, while the others works, this adds up but doesn't change it, completely. Not saying is better, just a choice. The suggesting of explaining why is just for future users as myself can read it and understand it.

Comment: If this is the answer you prefer then that's your prerogative but you could have pointed that out to the others who had answers you didn't like. That said, you encourage poor answers by accepting/rewarding them - if you're wary of future readers, help them out!

Comment: @TylerRoper hey I was chatting and trying the code, didn't even have the time to reply.

Comment: @rob.m Not to mention this answer **doesn't work**. Change the number in this example to one of the numbers in the middle. This answer removes the *last item from the array*. What if the number you want to remove is in the middle?

Comment: @TylerRoper adding that case too, but why down vote?, its so demotivating :(

Comment: @dhaker Well first you posted an answer without any explanation whatsoever, just code. Then, you edited it to add some detail, but the code doesn't work. While people make mistakes and we've all posted answers that don't work, you shouldn't submit an answer until it's sufficient and has at least *some* sort of explanation (or code that speaks for itself!). I try to come back and remove my downvotes once people spend the time to fix their answer, but as it stands right now, your answer is still wrong.

Comment: @dhaker Tag me when you've edited the answer and I'll happily remove my downvote.

Comment: @rob.m made it simpler

Comment: @dhaker Still doesn't work. Change the `data-thispostid` to one of the numbers in the middle.

Comment: @TylerRoper thank a lot for pointing out that bug, fixed it :)

Comment: @dhaker ...and what about if I remove the *first* number? `,29650,101647,63186,99616`

Comment: @TylerRoper i changed code to handle only number as asked by rob.m in problem. If i have to write code in general way then i have to write like what you wrote so not writing that to maintain uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the value from below hidden field

```
<input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value="29644,29650,63186,99616,101647">
```

By using  the below code

```
$(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
  var removeThisId = $(this).attr("data-thisPostId"); 

  $("#input_post_id").val($("#input_post_id").val().replace(removeThisId,'').replace(/,\s*$/, ""));

});
```

In your code, I just replace the below line

```
var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId");
```

To

```
var removeThisId = $(this).attr("data-thisPostId");
```

The problem of your code is the class .removeId is not available in your code or the class is not accessable. You can check to console the value of removeThisId for debugging your code or use any browser debugging tools

Comment: yes it's ok, got that issue about `this`, but what about the `comma`?

Comment: $("#input_post_id").val($("#input_post_id").val().replace(removeThisId,'')..replace(/,\s*$/, "")) use this to remove extra last comma